# Ensuring read-only access to API return values when a plugin architecture is present

Tags: c#, oop, class-design

I have a situation where I've exposed a plugin architecture to my class library, and I want others to be able to implement the interfaces I've created and have their custom implementations be used by the class.

I'm using dependency injection (specifically constructor injection) to accomplish this.

This works fine, except for the fact that I've tried to design the application with two conflicting goals:

- Consumers of the API should not be able to modify the return values; I've created custom read-only collections and objects, using `internal` on the setters and such to ensure no consumers can modify it
- Plugins, in other assemblies, *should* be able to access these internal methods and properties

These two goals are conflicting because there is no way for my API (or C# for that matter) to grant `internal` access (via `InternalsVisibleTo` or similar) to the plugin assemblies, but *not* to general consumers.

---

**Illustrative example**

Suppose we have three assemblies. My class (`Class`), a plugin assembly (`Plugin`), and a consumer assembly (`Consumer`).

An interface, `IReturnValue` specifies a return value of the API (some method or class in the `Class` assembly). The problem is this: I want `Plugin` to be able to set read-only (`internal`) properties and indexers on any given instance of `IReturnValue`, but I don't want `Consumer` code to be able to do this.

Since a plugin system is in play, I can't know ahead of time what assemblies to grant `InternalsVisibleTo` to.

---

In this situation, **should I really care about consumers modifying return types?** It seems like it's their own fault if they do. And I can't think of any decent solution to solving this problem.

Comment: I think some sample code illustrating your problem would help tremendously. I am not sure I understood.

Comment: Was just working on that now. I know, it confuses me two :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already said in my comment, I am not sure I understood your question correctly.

I understood your question like this:

You have a class A that is used by Consumers and by Implementors. Consumers should only be able to *get* data, implementors should additionally be able to *set* data.

In this case, I would create one interface that is modeled to the consumers needs with only read access and one with read/write access for the implementors.

UPDATE after question update:
The read only interface for the consumer already exists: `IReturnValue` and should be used for this purpose.

All you need to do now is to create an interface that is either write only or that is read/write, depending on the needs of the API.

Comment: I agree with this approach. I think sometimes we confuse compiler visibility flags with security mechanisms. They are there as a hint to the consumers. If they really wanted to modify your internal state, reflection would get them around any C# visibility constraints. So hint to the consumer that by accessing the read/write interface they know what they are doing.

Comment: To your update: so, internally, (and across plugins), I could use something like `IReturnValueInternal` to indicate that it is read/write. Then, I return a `IReturnValue` to the consumer?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Yes. However, I would try to find a better name. `IReturnValueInternal` doesn't communicate much.

Comment: Ok. I'll play around with some different names. Thanks again.